# config.php missed in my app/etc directory

Tags: magento2

`app/etc/config.php` missed.

am also following code:

1)`bin/magento module:install`

2)`bin/magento module:upgrade`

3)`bin/magento module:enable`

4)`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

use `bin/magento module:enable --all`, it will regenerate `app/etc/config.php`

Answer (score 1):

config.php should be generated when you first setup Magento 2. If you've cloned a repo instead, then it won't exist. As Khoa said, copy from another Magento 2 source and it will regenerate upon running the setup scripts.

If you don't have another source to take it from, then install a Magento 2 site from scratch on your machine and take it from there once completed.